# Extracting expression from csv field

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I'm trying to extract the value that comes after `word=` in CSV file that looks like this:

```
1473228800,0.0,word=google.sentence=Android.something=not_set
1480228800,100.0,word=google_analytics.number=not_set.country=US.source=internet
1493228800,0.0,location=NY.word=Android.sentence=not_set.something=not_set.type=gauge
```

and the output I need is (it's important for me to **only** print "word" and it's value):

```
1473228800,0.0,word=google
1480228800,100.0,word=google_analytics
1493228800,0.0,word=Android
```

I tried using `sed` and `awk`, but each gave me soultion for only few of the csv file.
This is my last try using `awk`:

```
awk -F "," '{sub(/.*word.*=(.*)\.*/,"word=\1", $3);print $1","$2","$3}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F, '{match($3,/word=[^.]+/); print $1,$2,substr($3,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' OFS=',' file
```

The output:

```
1473228800,0.0,word=google
1480228800,100.0,word=google_analytics
1493228800,0.0,word=Android
```

---

- `match($3,/word=[^.]+/)` - to match the needed sequence within the 3rd field
- `substr($3,RSTART,RLENGTH)` - to extract matched sequence from the 3rd field

> The *match()* function sets the predefined variable *RSTART* to the
>   index. It also sets the predefined variable *RLENGTH* to the length in
>   characters of the matched substring.

Comment: Thanks, it works.
Just another thing, if I want to get every word*, it gives back all the sentence and not just the expression I want, how to I need to change the command to get sentences with:
date,value,some=some.word_some=linux.try=right

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
awk -F, '{sub(/.*word/,"word",$3);sub(/\..*/,"",$3);print $1,$2,$3}' OFS=","   Input_file
```

Making field separator as , then substituting >8word with string word. Then substituting from DOT to everything with NULL in $3 as we don't need it as per your question. Then printing the first, second and third fields set output field separator as comma then.